# node-webkit Right Click a Link and Open in Default Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I have an iframe in my node-webkit application. I'd like the user to be able to right click links ( tags) in the iframe and be able to select an "Open in Browser" option to open the link using their system's default browser.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and below is the code for each of the files.

You can download the entire [file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxelXtnaMWq-Zi1vem1LUTVqZmc/view?usp=sharing)

INDEX.HTML

```
<iframe src="iframe.html" frameborder="2" height="200px" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

IFRAME.HTML

```
<body style="background:#cecece;">

    <h2>This is an iFrame</h2>

    <a href="#" id="link">Right click here</a>

    <script>

        // Load native UI library
        var nw = require('nw.gui');

        // Create an empty menu
        var menu = new nw.Menu(); 

        // Add an item with label
        menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({ 
            label: 'open in browser',
            click: function(e) {
                nw.Shell.openExternal('http://google.com'); 
            }
        }));

        // Listen for a right click on link
        document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.popup(e.x, e.y);
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "NW APP",
  "main": "index.html",
  "description": "Contextmenu from within an iframe"
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the script for the menu be in index.htm?

Comment: @user6245342 I don't know how easy it is to manipulate a page within an iframe from the parent page. So having the script for the menu in the iframe.html instead of the index.html made more sense.